# Why is the CDF of a sample uniformly distributed

Tags: density-function, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, intuition

I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Probability_distributions_of_order_statistics) that given a sample $ X_1,X_2,...,X_n $ from a continuous distribution with cdf $ F_X $, the sample corresponding to $ U_i = F_X(X_i) $ follows a standard uniform distribution.

I have verified this using qualitative simulations in Python, and I was easily able to verify the relationship.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats

xs = scipy.stats.norm.rvs(5, 2, 10000)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(9, 3))
axes[0].hist(xs, bins=50)
axes[0].set_title("Samples")
axes[1].hist(
    scipy.stats.norm.cdf(xs, 5, 2),
    bins=50
)
axes[1].set_title("CDF(samples)")
```

Resulting in the following plot:

[image: Plot showing the sample of a normal distribution and the cdf of the sample.]

I am unable to grasp why this happens. I assume it has to do with the definition of the CDF and it's relationship to the PDF, but I am missing something ...

I would appreciate it if someone could point me to some reading on the subject or help me get some intuition on the subject.

EDIT: The CDF looks like this:

[image: CDF of the sampled distribution]

Comment: Compute the cdf of $F_X(X)$.

Comment: You would find a proof of this property (for continuous rv's) in any book about simulation as this is the basis of the inverse cdf simulation method.

Comment: Also try google-ing *probability integral transform*

Comment: @Xi'an It is good to point out the conclusion holds only for continuous random variables. Sometimes this result is mistakenly used for discrete random variables. On the other hand, also note many proofs involves the step $P(F(X) \leq x) = P(X \leq F^{-1}(x))$ in which assumes the strict monotonicity  of $F$, which is also a too strong assumption. The following link provides a rigorous summary on this topic:https://people.math.ethz.ch/~embrecht/ftp/generalized_inverse.pdf

Comment: @Zhanxiong the only condition necessary for $F$ is that it is càdlàg.

Comment: @AdamO Hmm, I don't think so. For a somewhat extreme example, $X \equiv 1$, then its cdf $F$ is càdlàg, however, $F(X) \equiv 1$, which is not uniform $(0, 1)$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong sorry you are right, the somewhat stronger condition of OP's statement is that, random variables following any càdlàg distribution $F$ can be "simulated" from inverse transformed uniform 0,1 RVs. That would be the case with your atomic DF.

Comment: @AdamO Yes, you are right. Your statement can actually be viewed as the opposite direction of the statement in this post.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Assume $F_X$ is continuous and increasing. Define $Z = F_X(X)$ and note that $Z$ takes values in $[0, 1]$. Then
$$F_Z(x) = P(F_X(X) \leq x) = P(X \leq F_X^{-1}(x)) = F_X(F_X^{-1}(x)) = x.$$
The derivative of $F_Z$ is constant so $Z$ is uniformly distributed.

A more specific way to see this is by observing that for a uniform random variable $U$ taking values in $[0, 1]$, $F_U(x) =  \int_R f_U(u)\,du =\int_0^x \,du =x$ so $F_Z(x) = F_U(x)$ for every $x\in[0, 1]$. Since $Z$ and $U$ has the same distribution function $Z$ must also be uniform on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Does it follow that Z has a uniform(0, 1) distribution?

Comment: @StatsSorceress Yes, you are right. $Z$ has a standard uniformly distribution on $(0,1).$

Comment: Why is $Z$ a random variable? If the CDF is a random variable, the pdf must be also a random variable but according to this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300187/is-probability-density-itself-a-random-variable) it seems that isn't the case.

Comment: @adosar: $Z$ is a random variable as a transform of another random variable $X$.

Answer (score 16):

Intuitively, perhaps it makes sense to think of $F(x)$ as a percentile function, e.g. $F(x)$ of a randomly generated sample from the DF $F$ is expected to fall below $x$. Alternately $F^{-1}$ (think inverse images, not a proper inverse function *per se*) is a "quantile" function. That is, $x = F^{-1}(p)$ is the point $x$ behind which falls $p$ proportion of the sample. The functional composition is measurably commutative $F \circ F^{-1} =_\lambda F^{-1} \circ F$.

The uniform distribution is the only distribution having a quantile function equal to a percentile function: they are the identity function. So the image space is the same as the probability space. $F$ maps *continuous* random variables into a (0, 1) space with equal measure. Since for any two percentiles, $a < b$, we have $P(F^{-1}(a) < x < F^{-1}(b)) = P(a < F(X) < b) = b-a$

Comment: I struggled for hours, but finally it clicked why the derived random variable $Y = F(X)$ is uniformly distributed. Your answer really helped, thanks a lot. It seems very much like in algebra where 1 was the multiplicative identity.

Answer (score 12):

Here's some intuition. Let's use a discrete example.

Say after an exam the students' scores are $X = [10, 50, 60, 90]$. But you want the scores to be more even or uniform. $h(X) = [25, 50, 75, 100]$ looks better.

One way to achieve this is to find the percentiles of each student's score. Score $10$ is $25\%$, score $50$ is $50\%$, and so on. Note that the percentile is just the CDF. So the CDF of a sample is "uniform".

When $X$ is a random variable, the percentile of $X$ is "uniform" (e.g. the number of $X$'s in $0-25$ percentile should be the same as the number of $X$'s in $25-50$ percentile). Therefore the CDF of $X$ is uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 5):

As I commented under several posts above, the key of a rigorous (and succinct) proof to the general continuous $F$ (that is, $F$ is not necessarily strictly increasing) is by introducing the *quantile function*:
\begin{align*}
\varphi(u) = \inf\{x: F(x) \geq u\}, \quad 0 < u < 1. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}
Note that this function is well defined for any distribution function $F$, regardless it has discontinuities or strictly increasing. This can also be used as a definition of the population $u$-quantile of a random variable whose distribution function is $F$. A graph of $\varphi(\cdot)$, which stresses its values at a discontinuity and a plateau point, is shown as follows (source: *Probability and Measure* (3rd edition), p.189):

[image: Quantile Function]

The most important property of $\varphi$ is its relationship with $F$: for any $0 < u < 1$:
\begin{align*}
F(\varphi(u)-) \leq u \leq F(\varphi(u)), \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align*}
where $F(\varphi(u)-) = \lim\limits_{x \uparrow \varphi(u)}F(x)$. From the graph, inequality $\eqref{2}$ is evident. The proof of $\eqref{2}$ will be relegated to the end of this answer.  Note that for a general $F$, $\eqref{2}$ is not equivalent to $F(\varphi(u)) = u$, as many "proofs" falsely claimed or relied on.

However, under the condition that $F$ is continuous (everywhere), $\eqref{2}$ of course reduces to $F(\varphi(u)) \leq u \leq F(\varphi(u))$, whence $F(\varphi(u)) = F(\varphi(u)-) = u$. It then follows that
\begin{align*}
P[F(X) < u] &= 1 - P[F(X) \geq u] \\
&= 1 - P[X \geq \varphi(u)] = 
P[X < \varphi(u)] = F(\varphi(u)-) = u. \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align*}
In the second equality above, we used the definition $\eqref{1}$. Now by
$\eqref{3}$ and the continuity (from above) of the probability measure, we have for $0 < u < 1$:
\begin{align*}
P[F(X) \leq u] = \lim\limits_{h \downarrow 0}P[F(X) < u + h] = 
\lim\limits_{h \downarrow 0}(u + h) = u. 
\end{align*}
This shows that $F(X) \sim U(0, 1)$, and the proof is complete.

---

##### *Proof of $\eqref{2}$*

By definition $\eqref{1}$, if $y < \varphi(u)$, then $F(y) < u$ (otherwise, $\varphi(u)$ would not be a lower bound of the set $S_u := \{x: F(x) \geq u\}$ as $F(y) \geq u$ and $y < \varphi(u)$). This implies that $F(\varphi(u)-) = \lim\limits_{y \uparrow \varphi(u)}F(y) \leq u$.

On the other hand, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, since $\varphi(u) + n^{-1}$ is not the infimum of $S_u$, there exists $x_n \in S_u$ such that $x_n < \varphi(u) + n^{-1}$, whence $F(\varphi(u) + n^{-1}) \geq F(x_n) \geq u$ by the monotonicity of $F$. This implies by the right-continuity of $F$ that $F(\varphi(u)) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}F(\varphi(u) + n^{-1}) \geq u$.

This completes the proof of $\eqref{2}$.

Comment: Same approach has been used in introducing the cdf by Sidney Resnick (along with the same diagram!) in his book (although the approach itself is not unique and ingenious in itself). Anyway +1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CDF of a random variable has uniform distribution in the interval $(0, 1)$ because the distribution of its CDF has a form $F(Y \leq y) = y.$ In a formal way, if $X $ is a random variable, then $ F(X) \sim \textrm{Unif}(0,1).
$

Proof:

To understand this special property, the key is to understand the inverse function which is generated from the relationship between $ X $ and its CDF. For example, if $ X$  is a Pareto distribution with parameter a and has CDF as:

$$ F(x)= \begin{cases} 1 - 1/ x^a, &\textrm{if}~ x > 1,\\
       0 &\textrm{if}~ x \leq 1\end{cases}$$

The inverse function is $ y = F(x) = 1 - 1/x^a.$

Thus we can know $x$ if we know $y$ and vice versa, leading us to the inverse function:

$$ x = 1/(1-y)^{1/a}$$

in a formal way: $F^{-1}$ is the inverse function of $F.$ If $F(x) = y $ then $F^{-1}(y) = x.$ In the above example:

$$ F^{-1}(y) = 1/(1-y)^{1/a} $$

For an easier example, if we have half of people score below 70 then its CDF $F(70) = 1/2,$ its inverse function $F^{-1}(1/2) = 70.$
Now we can see the act of inversing a function is to change from x to y and from $y$ to $x.$ Thus $F^{-1}(F(x)) = x$ and $F^{-1}(F(y)) = y.$

Now we are able to generate the proof we need.
X is random variable. We have $F(x) = y $then:

$F^{-1}(y) = x,$ and $F(F^{-1}(y)) = y $ because it is just another way
to say $F(x) = y . $

We find the distribution of variable Y by finding its cumulative distribution:

$$\Pr(Y < y) = \Pr(F(X) < y) = \Pr(X < F^{-1}(y)) = F(F^{-1}(y)) = y;$$

therefore $\Pr(Y < y) = y $ which makes it a uniform distribution $\textrm{Unif}(0,1). $

Comment: Hi. Welcome to CV. This is a MathJax-enabled site.
Please use this facility
to typeset your mathematical expressions for better legibility. For a quick 
guide, check this Meta
CV post: [Instructions on
how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated).

Comment: I have done for you this time. And I am pretty sure there are typographical errors which I have not fixed. Check yourself and correct them where needed.

Comment: @User1865345 thank you for your kindness. I will check the link you provided. Sorry, this is the first time I join this website. Have a nice day!